# Url With only get parameters executing with curl in php:getting error

Tags: php, api, curl

I am sending sms sending api through php curl.

```
<?php
$number='XXXXXX';
$message="Hello world";
$url='http://XXx/api/sendmsg.php?user=XXXXX&pass=XXX&sender=SPOTMT&phone='.$number.'&text='.$message.'&priority=ndnd&stype=normal';
echo $url;
echo httpGet($url);
function httpGet($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

i will get the error message from the api service ,however  when i copy  the url from this `echo $url` directly on browser  it will works fine.
But when using `curl` i will get the error message.

Here is it

> Sender ID Does not Exist or Pending or Route Invalid!

With `curl` it didn't worked.

Comment: Set-up an user-agent to the curl request. Most likely it is being filtered

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: "Sender ID Does not Exist ?" have you checked the sender id or passing right  parameter

Comment: But it will works fine when i execute through browser

Comment: Does it prompts for any window while executing on browser, for asking password or username ?

Answer (score 1):

Add an user-agent to your curl request as the back-end might filter requests having the default curl user-agent.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

Comment: is there any documentation from the api that might help? :)

Comment: Nop:(  they provide only with urls and parameters not even any error codes:)

Comment: You can inspect the request in the browser, in the network tab of the developer tools, right click the request and _"copy as CURL"_ then try to replicate this in php

Comment: Ok let me try that

Comment: do urlencode(your text meaasge) . Before submitting it to CURL

Answer (score 0):

use urlencode() for encoding your message before submitting it to CURL